# Parsing String Java

Tags: java, string, parsing

I got a String:

```
["4fd1cf1783353a15415","4ffecf87fcc40d110a965626"]
```

or

```
["4fd5f684815345","4fd6ef3e60a676854651","4fd83c33c19164512153"]
```

And I'd like to store every id (eg. 4fd5f684815345, 4fd6ef3e60a676854651, 4fd83c33c19164512153...)  in a independant String (or ArrayList).

How to parse it, because the String can be dynamic (1,2,3 values or more)?

OR JSON Array Parsing:

My JSON

```
"idCards":[
"4fc52f95egvt418541515",
"4fd1d05454151541545115"
],
```

A part of my code:

```
msg3 = (JSONArray) myobject.get("idCards");
System.out.println(msg3.toJSONString());
```

The result:

```
[4fc52f95egvt418541515","4fd1d05454151541545115"]
```

I'd like this 2 values in 2 differents String.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You might wanna try regex, you can use delimiter to split 'em up. I am not quite sure about the code though. :)

Comment: Please clarify your question. You have a String *array* in that format? You have string data coming from a file or socket in that format? with the [ and ] and double-quotes?

Comment: This is a JSON data structure. The correct way to parse this is to use a JSON library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added some clarifications.

Comment: You converted from a JSON String into a JsonArray, the next step is to convert this to a Java List. And you're done. I have modified my answer to show you.

Answer (score 4):

It would appear to be that this could be a JSON String. In which case, you may make use of a Java JSON Library to help you parse that into Java native objects.

http://www.json.org/

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

```
String data = "[\"4fd5f684815345\",\"4fd6ef3e60a676854651\",\"4fd83c33c19164512153\"]";

// parse JSON String to JSON Array
JsonArray array = (JsonArray) (new JsonParser()).parse(data);

// build a Java ArrayList
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

// for each item in JsonArray, add to Java ArrayList
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    stringList.add((array.get(i)).getAsString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I make a number of assumptions here:

- Assume no spaces before and after the delimiting `[`, `]`, `,`
- Assume no `,` and `"` character in the Strings you want to extract

  ```
  input.substring(1, input.length() - 1).replaceAll("\\\"", "").split(",");
  ```

  Or if you don't want to mess with regular expression (`replaceAll` function works with regular expression), then you can use `replace` method:

  ```
  input.substring(1, input.length() - 1).replace("\"", "").split(",");
  ```

Due to the assumptions above, this answer is very brittle. Consider using JSON parser if the data is really JSON.

Comment: @dacwe: Taken care of by the substring. Need to update the answer with assumption.

Comment: Too fast, sorry, however, use `replace` instead of `replaceAll` when replacing non-regex.

Comment: @dacwe: I really don't know: Can you remove character with `replace`?

Comment: Yes you can, check [it out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).

Comment: @dacwe: It is likely that it is implemented with `Pattern` class, though. OpenJDK does http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.replace%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Cjava.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: Even though it uses the same in the background the interface is *much* easier, for example the `"` character doesn't need to triple-escaped.

Answer (score 2):

I fully agree with the JSON answers, but if this is a one-off hack, you could just do this:

```
    String input = "[\"4fd5f684815345\",\"4fd6ef3e60a676854651\",\"4fd83c33c19164512153\"]";
    input = input.replace("[", "");
    input = input.replace("]", "");
    input = input.replace("\"", "");
    String[] parts = input.split(",");
```

Comment: `String.replace` also replaces all occurrences so no need to use `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String str = "[\"4fd5f684815345\",\"4fd6ef3e60a676854651\",\"4fd83c33c19164512153\"]";
    String strArry[] = null;

    if(str.trim().length() > 0){
        str = str.substring(1 , str.length()-1).replaceAll("\\\"", "");
        strArry = str.split(",");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If s is the input string, it can just be as simple as

```
String[] idArray = s.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\"]", "").split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be more secure (because '`,`' may be a decimal separator) to split with `("\",\"")`, and not remove trailing `"` in replaceAll, here subtring do not parse all the string :

```
final String str = "[\"4fd5f684815345\",\"4fd6ef3e60a676854651\",\"4fd83c33c19164512153\"]";

final String strArray[] = str.substring(2, str.length() - 2).split("\",\"");
final ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

for (final String string : strArray) {
    al.add(string);
    System.out.println(string);
}
System.out.println(al);
```

for (final String string : strArray) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

Output :

```
4fd5f684815345
4fd6ef3e60a676854651
4fd83c33c19164512153
[4fd5f684815345, 4fd6ef3e60a676854651, 4fd83c33c19164512153]
```